# No GPS reception on Asus Slider SL101

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gps, network-signal

I am the owner of an ASUS SL101 tablet, runing Android 4.0 (ICS). Using the "GPS Test" app,  I cannot get any GPS signals, even when standing outside for extended periods of time. I have a standalone GPS that has no problems getting GPS signals under the smae conditions. Is this a harware or software issue, and is there any way to get any reception on the tblet? One of the tablet's primary purposes was to be a GPS, and at the moment the function is completely useless. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you possibly post up the system log from the phone when you're trying to connect to the GPS?

Comment: @Peanut How do I find the system log?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device so set up the PC and device and then turn on the GPS when you're outside/near a window/somewhere where you can get GPS, then plug the phone back into the PC and take the log off it. Or there's this application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector&hl=en but the reviews for it are mixed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I would say you probably have a hardware issue here. I have had two phones do similar things, one did not connect at all, the other would connect only for a moment before basically shutting the GPS down. Both of these ended up being hardware issues resulting in me returning the devices. My best advice would be to try multiple apps to test GPS signal, ( I use [GPS Status](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHMQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.eclipsim.gpsstatus2%26hl%3Den&ei=hei_T7eGIois8AS9nfzHCw&usg=AFQjCNG0nV-tuT1-eVpHv1e9tWO7rcBOeA&sig2=bM71ty2qIWCco3CawIjvIg) or [Tricorder](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/app/tricorder)), and **if you get no GPS reception from any of them**, contact your manufacturer, or the people you purchased it from. Usually resellers will refund or replace products that malfunction without provocation.

If you do get signal with any of them or you get partial GPS signal sometimes, I'd still contact your reseller or manufacturer with the issues, while continuing to test it in different places alongside other (Android 4.0, if possible) devices.

Comment: I used GPS Test, I will try the two apps you listed. I am reluctant to return it, as I have done so three times already.

Comment: That's rotten luck :/ I feel the GPS malfunctioning is far too common of an issue. As I said, I've had two do it, and it kills a lot of things I would like to use my phone for.

Comment: So this is the manufacturer's fault and not Android's, correct?

Comment: It was in both of my cases.

Comment: What do you mean by that? What did android do wrong?

Comment: I meant the hardware was the issue in both my cases, not Android